# Dealing with prices in different currencies when handling payments by yourself and Invoices

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, payment, payment-processing

I have a table Invoice and InvoiceItems and I'll handle payments by myself. A client can pay in different currencies, but the prices of the services I sell are in a single currency, say, Euro. Or at the moment, at least.
My question is:

a) should I create one more table, InvoicePayments, where I'd store information in which currency a payment has been made as the currency_id field

b) or should I keep the currency_id field in the table Invoices?

In the case #a I'd generate new records in InvoicePayments each time a client changes their mind about the currency in which they want to pay while keeping a single record in Invoice

In the case #b I'd generate new records in Invoice each time a client changes their mind about the currency in which they want to pay.

Which one is better? For me they're more or less the same. But .... maybe there's something I don't know about yet.

Please don't tell the phrase "it depends on what you need" -- everything always depends on what I need.

Comment: You'll get the maximum flexibility if you keep your `Invoices` in your reference currency (euro), and you let the `InvoicePayments` deal with currency exchange rates and have the actual *payment* details. Also, this way, an Invoice could even be split into different payments, if the need arises.

Comment: @joanolo, thanks, quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, if there's any way to *buy* accounting software instead of building it, do that. My first professional programming job was programming an application that involved international accounting. It's mind-numbing. I saw an actual fist-fight between vice presidents over how to apply foreign currency exchange rates.

But if you have to build it, you need to store not only which currency all or part of an invoice is paid in, but also the exchange rate or effective value that applies to that payment. The exchange rate or effective value shouldn't be updatable by everyday users.

Exchange rates vary over time. So a payment row that looks like this doesn't tell you whether a 100 EUR invoice from October 3, 2016, has been paid in full.

```
invoice  pmt_date    pmt_currency  pmt_amount
--
10132    2016-10-03  USD           89.00
```

The exchange rate today is 1 EUR = 1.0681 USD. The exchange rate on Oct 3, 2016, was 1 EUR = 1.1236 USD. Either of these following tables could store that kind of fact.

```
invoice  pmt_date    pmt_currency  pmt_amount  exchange_rate
--
10132    2016-10-03  USD           89.00       1.1236
```

```
invoice  pmt_date    pmt_currency  pmt_amount  pmt_amount_eur
--
10132    2016-10-03  USD           89.00       100.00
```

The rules about which exchange rate applies to each payment depends on the application.

Comment: how do you infer which currency is more expensive from the exchange rate in your table ? is it `1 EUR = 1.1236 USD` or `1 USD = 1.1236 EUR`?